# how to import a apk file into android application?

Tags: android

i have an android application in which i need to use a calendar. Since Android does not offer any default calendar widget, i am using an external library....
The apk of the library is available...how do i import this apk into my android application?
if this cannot be done, how to import any code into my android application?

thank you in advance.

Comment: Related: (how to call into other applications) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122851/how-can-i-use-apk-file-into-my-own-application-android

Comment: in apk file does not content any source code so can not use class of apk file. to add a library  you have to add JAR file.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot import an APK. What you have to import is either the source code or a JAR file. How can you do that? If you are using eclipse just edit your Build Path property for your Android Project and add the JAR (in the case you have a JAR).

Answer (score 0):

Make it as a jar library and then add to project.

Comment: how to add the jar file to my android application?

Comment: I assume you use Eclipse. Right click on the project -> Proprties ->Java Build Path (tab) -> Add External Jars. Using this steps you can add External Jar File.

Comment: yes. can i convert my apk file to a jar file. i have to use a calendar control and ancal only gives out apk files.